# Spring cloud sleuth not appending keys to Hibernate query logs

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

When I am using spring cloud sleuth, I am observing that it is appending application name and key details for all the application logs.

But this is not happening for Hibernate logs or jpa queries.

Is there any way to achieve this using sleuth

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Brave integration with JDBC via py6spy - https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/tree/master/instrumentation/p6spy

Extract from the docs:

```
brave-instrumentation-p6spy

This includes a tracing event listener for P6Spy (a proxy for calls to your JDBC driver). It reports to Zipkin how long each statement takes, along with relevant tags like the query.

P6Spy requires a spy.properties in your application classpath (ex src/main/resources). brave.p6spy.TracingP6Factory must be in the modulelist to enable tracing.

modulelist=brave.p6spy.TracingP6Factory
url=jdbc:p6spy:derby:memory:p6spy;create=true

In addition, you can specify the following options in spy.properties

remoteServiceName

By default the zipkin service name for your database is the name of the database. Set this property to override it

remoteServiceName=myProductionDatabase

includeParameterValues

When set to to true, the tag sql.query will also include the JDBC parameter values.

Note: if you enable this please also consider enabling 'excludebinary' to avoid logging large blob values as hex (see http://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configandusage.html#excludebinary).

includeParameterValues=true
excludebinary=true

spy.properties applies globally to any instrumented jdbc connection. To override this, add the zipkinServiceName property to your connection string.

jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydatabase?zipkinServiceName=myServiceName

This will override the remoteServiceName set in spy.properties.

The current tracing component is used at runtime. Until you have instantiated brave.Tracing, no traces will appear.
```